# How to Configure Angular2 on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, angular, amazon-ec2, configuration

I've had success building the Angular2 Quickstart app on my local machine, but I'd like to jump forward to setting it up on an AWS instance. The issue is that I ssh into the instance and so the `npm start` command doesn't load the app into my local browser. Even the "External" addresses provided don't work, even with an elastic IP assigned and the corresponding port opened. I've also looked through the `node_modules/lite-server` files to update any necessary configuration changes, but I haven't found how to alter it properly.

Can anyone point me to some resources that can help me get started wit angular2 on AWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first, there are some differences between your localhost and the aws EC2 instance.

- Your computer is a graphical computer with a browser, the ec2 vm is just a command line based linux server and has no browser installed on it.
- `npm start`, just like "`grunt someTask`" has extra stuff built into the steps that wouldn't make sense on a linux server... i.e. automatically opening your browser window and doing live-reload for active development, etc.
- the EC2 vm is a place where you want to treat it more like beta server or production server, meaning that you dont start and stop your app with npm start, instead you want to start it with `node yourAppFile.js`, and you are merely running it to see if it works. You don't develop here.

Also, the ec2 vm itself is guarded / protected by a security group, and that allows very few ports to be accessed from the outside world by default, so you've got to go edit the "inbound rules" of the security group and add a rule that essentially allows: `"custom" --> "the node port" --> "your IP"`. Doing so will make it possible to connect to it using the `vm-public-ip:port-of-node-app` which will look something like this in your browser: `56.128.17.42:3000`. And because you put your own IP in that rule, no other IP addresses would be able to load it in their browsers... just you. If you were to say "0.0.0.0/0" in the ip field, that allows all users anywhere to connect.

Answer (score 1):

I would test with curl on your local machine to make sure it's up and running.  You can do that with "curl http://localhost:3000/ (change 3000 to whatever port you are running on).

If that is working okay, you may have an issue with security groups.  Go to the security group topic on the EC2 page and select the security group for your server and make sure that you have the port opened from your IP address (you can google "what is my ip" if you don't know it).  You can just open it the whole world if you're not worried about security.

Comment: Do i execute the `curl` statement inside the shh or from my local machine terminal? What does curling the `localhost` do?

Comment: Curl is a command line library for making requests of different protocols, including http. I would start by executing it on the ec2 instance. Localhost is an alias to whatever computer you are on. It usually points at the loopback address(127.0.0.1) and not in any particular network interface card.  If it works on localhost from the ec2 instance then you know the server is running.